# Mysql - Get Sum of All distinct rows based on other value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this,

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| num | amount | value |
+-----+--------+-------+
|   1 |     12 |     1 |
|   1 |     12 |     1 |
|   2 |     13 |     1 |
|   4 |     15 |     0 |
|   2 |     13 |     1 |
|   3 |     14 |     1 |
|   3 |     14 |     1 |
|   1 |     12 |     1 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

I want to sum the 'amount' column based on distinct 'num' column where 'value' is equal to 1,
for example, after running following query,

```
select DISTINCT num, amount, value from test where value =1 ;
```

distinct 'num' based table is

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| num | amount | value |
+-----+--------+-------+
|   1 |     12 |     1 |
|   2 |     13 |     1 |
|   3 |     14 |     1 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

so i want the final result to be

> 12+13+14 = 39.

one more thing is that

> i cant use subquery.

because it is already part of another query as well.

here is the script of my table is

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `test`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2', '13', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('4', '15', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2', '13', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('3', '14', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('3', '14', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
```

Comment: just use sum `select sum(amount) from test where value =1 ;`

Comment: Are you expecting only 1 row int the result set?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes exactly 1 row result . the final ans is to be 39

Comment: why you can't use a subquery?

Comment: can you post desire output?

Comment: @Pankajkatiyar the desire output is 39.

Comment: What happens if any 'num' column have 2  different amounts?

Comment: @BhavikaZimbar it is not possible in my case

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temp table containing distinct values and using `SUM()` to calculate amount. Your query will go like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT t.`num`, t.`amount` 
       FROM test t 
       WHERE t.`value`=1
     ) temp
```

Comment: @AmeerHamza I've added a solution. Check if this helps.

Comment: he said he can't use subquery

Comment: right.. i cant use subquery in it :( that is the restriction

Comment: @MattiaNocerino It is not possible without sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select num,sum(amount)/Count(*)
 from test
 where value = 1
 group by num
 order by num
```

Comment: that didnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that every num has the same value (if not, how should you pick one?)

so, this will work:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount)
FROM test
WHERE value = 1
```

Comment: the 'amount' cant be distinct. The distinct must be 'num' column. it didnt solve the issue :(

Comment: Why? I tried this and it's working. If the amount cannot be distinct, which one are you going to sum, let's say, if there are 2 row with the `num` set at   `1` and different `amounts` values like `12` and `13`?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino The OP meant, amount can be same for different `num` so `DISTINCT` amount can not be used.

Comment: @Shaharyar ok i get it now, thanks. But my question still remain i guess... is it possible that same `num` have different `amounts`?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino no it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT num, amount, VALUE FROM test WHERE VALUE =1) AS temp  ;
```

Comment: Is it helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the solution

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `test`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2', '13', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('4', '15', '0');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2', '13', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('3', '14', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('3', '14', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');

-- ----------------------------
-- Insert the result set into temp table and then use sum().
-- ----------------------------


SELECT DISTINCT `num` , `amount` 
INTO #tmp
FROM test 
WHERE `value`   =1

SELECT * FROM #tmp

SELECT sum(`amount`) as amount FROM #tmp
```